# General approach: to prove finiteness of cohomology theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is a rather general (and vague) question.

In all cohomology theory, the finitenss result is one of the central things to prove.

**My question is this:**

Is there any pattern (unifying structure) for these proofs (in different cohomology theories)? i.e., one starts from something, and then use some common tools, etc...

For example, it seems to me, one always starts with certain "affine" space, and then use certain glueing to prove it for general spaces...

Comment: Yup, that's pretty vague. Different cohomology theories (coherent,  etale, singular...) use different techniques to get finiteness results. I would certainly be thrilled to see a unified treatment.

Comment: For coherent cohomology the finiteness is false for affine spaces, so you can't start with those. For projective varieties, the usual proof is by reduction to projective space. I don't remember the proof for proper varieties.

Comment: For etale cohomology, the proof for non-proper varieties is highly nontrivial and involves Deligne's devissage method.

Comment: The proof for sheaf cohomology of coherent sheaves on compact complex manifolds is through elliptic partial differential equations.